# EJS not converting message to html format

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm working a shoutbox system where I want to make any URLs into actual clickable links;

What i have so far is

```js
<p class="da-msg-content" style="white-space: pre-wrap">
  <%=docs[i].msg.replace(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig, `<a href="$1"> $1 </a>`) %>
</p>
```

this replaces anything like https://example.com to an actual link but instead it does

`<a href="https://example.com"> https://example.com </a>` instead of making it legitimate HTML

Example:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, figured it out `<%- ... %>` instead of `<%= ... %>`.

Difference:

`<%- ... %>` without escaping.

`<%= ... %>` escapes anything within.